Migrating current legacy driver to the latest version on ADF link service
Getting this on ADF "Your pipeline is currently utilizing legacy drivers. To avoid any unexpected behavior, please migrate to the latest driver version at your earliest convenience. Click here to view the impacted linked service." How do I migrate to the latest version?
I cannot find steps online. I am assuming this has to do with backing up the pipeline and importing the data back in.

Presumably your pipeline is using drivers to connect to your source/target systems so you just need to upgrade the drivers - as the warning suggests

On the 23rd of August 2024 Azure released the details of the Planned Connector and Driver deprecation.
The instructions for Snowflake state:

To upgrade the Snowflake linked service, create a new Snowflake linked service and configure it by referring to Linked service properties.

